# Creating a secondary login in the same application

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms

I have an existing ASP.NET webforms application that uses forms authentication.

I am now creating a mini-site within this same application
I have a separate users table for users who will be logging into this mini-site also.

All the pages will be under a new folder like:

```
/mini-app/
/mini-app/login.aspx
/mini-app/logout.aspx
etc.
```

Since I cannot have 2 forms authentication in the same application, what options do I have in terms of authentication for this mini-application?

Comment: You can use role based security with form based authentication. In that way you don't need to ask users to login to second app again. You can check if user belong to a role say "MiniApp_Users" and grant them access to your second app.

Comment: I agree with @Hakunamatata. Why have an application within another one? Role based auth seems to make sense here.